# Parse iOS SDK deadlock during saveAllInBackground with circular relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have two PFObject subclasses that reference each other.  I'll call them A & B.

If I try to save a collection of [A,B] twice in rapid succession, this will occasionally deadlock when the two operations try to merge the data from the save.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a bit of time debugging this so I'm going to explain what's going on, and how to avoid it for the next person who encounters this.

If you're lucky enough to catch this while connected to the debugger, pause the execution, and find two threads that are doing the following.

The deadlock occurs after the two collections have finished saving.

**On Thread 1:**

**A** calls **PFObject#canBeSerializedAfterSaving:withCurrentUser:error** and synchronizes the thread with its lock.

**A** iterates through its properties to determine whether it can be serialized.

When **A** iterates through its properties, it encounters **B** and tries to retrieve **B**'s objectId.  **B** then synchronizes the thread with its lock while it accesses its state in PFObject#state

Thread 1 is now locked in the order A,B

**Meanwhile, over on thread 2:**

**B** calls **PFObject#canBeSerializedAfterSaving:withCurrentUser:error** and synchronizes the thread with its lock.

**B** iterates through its properties to determine whether it can be serialized.

When **B** iterates through its properties, it encounters **A** and tries to retrieve **A**'s objectId.  **A** then synchronizes the thread with its lock while it accesses its state in PFObject#state

Thread 2 is now locked in the order B,A

**Classic deadlock**

This is the classic deadlock scenario.  Two locks are obtained in different order.  This may be a bug in Parse.  I didn't see an easy way to fix it, but there is an easy workaround.

**Workaround**

Fundamentally the problem here is that I'm saving two collections of A and B.  Because B is a child of A, I only need to save A.  Parse automatically will save instances of B if they have changed.